# JPA, Hibernate: OneToOne mapping with foreign key only

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Environment:

- Hibernate 4.1.6.final
- Spring 3.1.2.release
- Spring JPA 1.1.0.release
- PostgreSQL 9.1-901-1.jdbc4

I decided to rephrase the questions.

There are 2 tables:

```
public company
{
  private Long id;
  private Long name;
  private address table_address;
}
public address
{
  private Long id;
  private String address;
  private Long company_id;
}
```

Note: both table id is sequential and no related. Except `table.address.company_id` is foreign key of company.

how to do mapping? what result i expected is:

```
"company":{
            "id":4,
            "name":"company name",
            "address":{
                         "id":3,
                         "address":"anywhere",
                         "company_id":4
                      }
          }
```

So can somebody teach me that, how to map this 2 table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what you want is One-to-One mapping between `Company` and `Address`

just add `@OneToOne` annotation to table_address field of Company class:

```
 public class Address {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        private String address;
        @OneToOne
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
        private Company company;

        //getters and setters
    }

public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "company",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address companyAddress;

    //getters and setters
}
```

<sub>Apart from the problem:
respect java naming convention, in your case class name should start with capital letter and the next word in the variable name too. i.e. *company* should be **Company** and *address* should be **Address**, `private address table_address;` change to `private Address companyAddress;`</sub>

**Updated solution**

```
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String address;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "company",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address companyAddress;

    //getters and setters
}
```

from stupidfrog: if u using @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn, then the id join wrong. the id join with both primary but not address table company_id

here is the reference from hibernate
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html
the example 1

Comment: In address table, the company_id field name can be any,how does those table join?

Comment: @Stupidfrog in question you have mentioned **table.address.company_id is foreign key of company.** so the datatype of _company_id_ of `address` and _id_ of `company` class should be same.

Comment: ya, it is foreign key, but in table entity, there is no any annotation to declare that company_id is company.id foreign key. However, even using method u provided, will prompt this ERROR: column company.address_id does not exist

Comment: i just found the solution, which is 90% close to ur solution. the only different is the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn switch to @JoinColumn(name = "company_id"), for ur solution. i will test later and will update also

Comment: @AbhishekNayak If I used your updated solution for One-to-one mapping. The Foreign key `company_id` is not getting inserted inside `Address` table. Can you help.

Answer (score 2):

You should create two entity classes as follows

COMPANY ENTITY

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "YOUR TABLE NAME")
    public company{

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Basic(optional = false)
       @Column(name = "COMPANY_ID")
       private Long id;
       @Column(name = "NAME")
       private Long name;
       @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
       @OneToOne(optional = false)
       private address table_address;
    }
```

ADDRESS ENTITY

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "YOUR TABLE NAME")
   public address{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Long company_id;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi,in your company entity, @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID"), where does ADDRESS_ID come from?

Comment: ADDRESS_ID is the column name of your ADDRESS table which is mapped to id in address class above

Comment: can you please provide error/exception if you are facing one?